# IllegalArgumentException и throws Exception

Tags: java

```
private String get() {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему если метод выбрасывает `IllegalArgumentException`, то его необязательно объявлять вместе с `throws`?
Иными словами, почему без проблем откомпилируется приведенный выше участок кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наследники классов RuntimeException и Error, и сами эти классы, относятся к unchecked (не проверяемым) исключениям. Они также перехватываются стандартным способом, но компилятор их не отслеживает.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался